# Bootstrap modal backdrop doesn't animate

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use separate files from Bootstrap for my project. Because I just need modal function from it.  CSS file that I use are _variables.scss, _vendor-prefixes.scss, _clearfix.scss, _modal.scss. And I use bootstrap.min.js. But why modal backdrop doesn't animate (fade in/out)? I've already added css transition on .modal-backdrop, but it didn't work.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Need to update your markup to make sure what trouble you are facing. May be a fiddle will be appreciated

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Benjamin Here is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6922502/sto/index.html

Comment: What button I have to press to get the issue?

Comment: @IrvinDominin Oops sorry, you can click "Request Appointment" button, the first orange one.